# Memory Inefficiency of the Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, memory

I'm writing a browser application for visualizing data. There's a very large amount of data (many millions of rows, potentially dozens of values per row), which in most languages can be stored with marginal overhead. Javascript seems to store the data in several times more space than is required, regardless of the browser, and I've narrowed it down to the array implementation. Here's an example comparing the memory storage of 10 million numbers versus 10 million arrays:

Default Usage:

Firefox: 90Mb

Chrome: 30Mb

IE: 10Mb

---

Numbers:

```
arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    arr.push(1);
}
```

Firefox: 170Mb - 90Mb = 80Mb = ~8 bytes per value

Chrome: 140Mb - 30Mb = 110Mb = ~11 bytes per value

IE: 90Mb - 10Mb = 80Mb = ~8 bytes per value

---

Arrays:

```
arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    arr.push(new Array());
}
```

Firefox: 970Mb - 90Mb = 880Mb = ~88 bytes per empty array

Chrome: 550Mb - 30Mb = 520Mb = ~52 bytes per empty array

IE: 930Mb - 10Mb = 920Mb = ~92 bytes per empty array

---

Does anyone have any explanations for this massive memory usage, and more importantly, does anyone have any solutions? There are ways of working around this problem, but using an array for each row would make the data far easier to work with. Hopefully there's a solution, as it's ridiculous that storing 10 million rows of data has a gigabyte overhead.

Comment: What kind of data are you working with? Have you considered [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)?

Comment: Odd to see IE winning something. :P Edit: Wait, no, it didn't actually win the array memory overhead war.

Comment: @Cory Have you considered lazy evaluation? Millions of arrays in memory - that doesn't sound like anything you'd want in any language, really. If you're doing data visualization, perhaps there's a way to only use what you need at that point. You might consider a library like [Lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/), especially if you're planning on doing a lot of processing of that data.

Comment: Try initializing your arrays like so: `arr = new Array(10000000);`. Modern JS engines can optimize when they know in advance the size and types of array. Also if the engines can guarantee that the same type of data will be in each member, they can take advantage of that as well.

Comment: I tried using the literal syntax `[]` instead of `new Array()` and this time, my browser didn't crash. @Cory, does that make a difference for you at all? (Edit: Okay, the browser didn't _crash_ = it just _froze_. Great.)

Comment: I'm using WebGL to make visualizations of a few million data points. The purpose of the software is to take basically any data, and given the type of each column (int, string, date, etc), display it in the browser with any columns as the x or y axis. I have something in Java that works, but am translating the front end to javascript so it can stay on a website.

If I need to, I'll store each column as an array with a few million values, but that would require a lot of rearranging code.

Lazy actually looks really useful, thanks! I'll check it out, but I don't know if it'll fix this problem.

Comment: Also [] is actually a little better in Chrome (not Firefox).
@cookie monster This actually just crashes it. I don't think it likes making an array that large up front)

Comment: @Cory You may also consider [Web Workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker) and [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) for your needs. Using a web worker would take some of the strain off of the UI thread, and asm.js provides some speed enhancements (although I'm not sure how well it might fare with large arrays). You may be able to use web workers in conjunction with Lazy.js by using Javascript promises - basically, you'll lazily evaluate your values using concurrent worker threads running asm.js. (Super cool, huh? :D)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this code block in the JS console on Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152  on OS X:

```
arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    arr.push(1);
}
```

My memory profile went from 52.1 MB to 68.4 MB = 16 MB, ~ 1.6 bytes per array.

As I am watching the browser sit idle, the memory profile has increased by .2 MB but now appears to be holding steady.

I ran the same code in Safari on the console and the memory profile actually went down slightly, suggesting to me that the browser's memory profile has less to do with the storage allocated to the array and more to do with whatever else is going on in the application.

UPDATED:

Starting with a Safari Web Content at 22.6 MB, I loaded this page:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

    function gen(){

        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            arr.push(new Array());
        }
        return arr.length;
    }
</script>


</head>
<body onload="alert(gen())">

</body>
</html>
```

Safari Web Content went from 22.6 MB up to 656.7 MB, then back down to 22.8 MB after the alert fired. Seems like each array is allocated a certain amount of RAM whether it has anything in it or not, which makes sense to me because in Javascript Arrays are sub-classes of Object.

Comment: Robert, you aren't incorrect - but this isn't an array of arrays, as the OP tested with.

Comment: I didn't know about the console thing. That's cool.

I tried it on a second computer in the console and the massive amount of memory exists on there too. I doubt Windows vs OSX would make that much of a difference. Maybe different browser settings? I'll try looking for something.

Comment: @Robert Chrome doesn't like me trying to do this - I attempted with the array literal `[]` but my instance froze. Are the results different if you use an array literal vs `new Array()`? Curiosity has the better of me at the moment.

Comment: @lunchmeat, Chrome seems fine with arr.push([]) as well. I will note that the Google Chrome Helper memory profile went up to 324 MB before dropping back down to 40 MB, while the Google Chrome process itself stayed flat. None of this code has caused a crash for me.

Comment: The array created by the gen function was not kept in memory and would have been garbage collected. This is why your memory went back down to ~22 MB after the alert fired.